# Boost Spirit Qi: binding to struct with vector of tuples

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Boost Spirit Qi parsing certainly is a unique application of C++, one that comes with a steep learning curve. In this case I am attempting to parse a string containing syntactically correct C++ list-initialization of a `struct` containing a `std::vector` of `std::tuple<std::string, short>`. Here is the declaration of the `struct`:

```
typedef std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int>> label_t;

struct BulkDataParmas
{
    std::string strUUID;
    short subcam;
    long long pts_beg;
    long long pts_len;
    long long pts_gap;
    label_t labels;
};
```

And here is my failing attempt to bind such a structure to a Qi attribute. The commented out `start` works as expected if I also comment out the `vector` member of the `struct`. (I've also tried `std::pair` instead of `std::tuple`).

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
(
    BulkDataParmas,
    (std::string, strUUID)
    (short, subcam)
    (long long, pts_beg)
    (long long, pts_len)
    (long long, pts_gap)
    (label_t, labels)
)



template <typename Iterator>
struct load_parser : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, BulkDataParmas(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type>
{
    load_parser() : load_parser::base_type(start)
    {
        namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
        namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
        using qi::attr;
        using qi::short_;
        using qi::int_;
        using qi::long_long;
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::xdigit;
        using qi::lexeme;
        using ascii::char_;
        using boost::proto::deep_copy;

        auto hex2_ = deep_copy(xdigit >> xdigit >> xdigit >> xdigit);
        auto hex4_ = deep_copy(hex2_ >> hex2_);
        auto hex6_ = deep_copy(hex4_ >> hex2_);
        auto fmt_  = deep_copy('"' >> hex4_ >> char_('-') >> hex2_ >> char_('-') >> hex2_ >> char_('-') >> hex2_ >> char_('-') >> hex6_ >> '"');
        uuid = qi::as_string[fmt_];

        quoted_string %= lexeme['"' >> +(char_ - '"') >> '"'];

        label = '{' >> quoted_string >> ',' >> int_ >> '}';

        start = '{' >>  uuid >> ',' >> short_ >> ',' >> long_long >> ',' >> long_long >> ',' >> long_long >> ',' >> '{' >> -(label >> *(',' >> label)) >>'}' >> '}';
//        start = '{' >>  uuid >> ',' >> short_ >> ',' >> long_long >> ',' >> long_long >> ',' >> long_long >> '}';
    }

private:

    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> uuid;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> quoted_string;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> label;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, BulkDataParmas(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> start;
};
```

Here is an example string to parse:

```
"{ \"68965363-2d87-46d4-b05d-f293f2c8403b\", 0, 1583798400000000, 86400000000, 600000000, { { \"motorbike\", 5 }, { \"aeroplane\", 6 } } };"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the two things you mentioned (which are correct), I'd suggest

1. some simplifications:

   ```
   uuid = '"' >> qi::raw [
       hex_<4>{} >> qi::repeat(3)['-' >> hex_<2>{}] >> '-' >> hex_<6>{}
   ] >> '"';
   ```

   Note, this removes all the sub-expressions, as-string and deepcopy, instead using the integer parser:

   ```
   template<int N> using hex_ = boost::spirit::qi::int_parser<std::intmax_t, 16, 2*N, 2*N>;
   ```

   The `raw[]` parser will nicely expose the source string matched.
2. Next up,

   ```
   quoted_string = '"' >> *~qi::char_('"') >> '"';
   ```

   Here I'd suggest using `*` to accept empty strings (this is frequently
    "the point" of quoted strings, so we can be explicit about embdedded
    whitespace or intentionally empty strings). Also, using `~charset` to be
    more efficient.

   Also dropped the `lexeme[]` because the rule is already declared without a skipper anyways.
3. Finishing up:

   ```
   label = '{' >> quoted_string >> ',' >> qi::int_ >> '}';

   start = qi::skip(ascii::space) [ '{'
       >> uuid      >> ','
       >> qi::auto_ >> ','
       >> qi::auto_ >> ','
       >> qi::auto_ >> ','
       >> qi::auto_ >> ','
       >> '{' >> -(label % ',') >> '}'
       >> '}' >> ';'
   ];
   ```

   Note that I incorporated the choice of skipper. so you don't have to tediously pass the correct thing in `phrase_parse`. The skipper is usually not something the caller should be able to change anyways.
4. Now let's also modernize the adaptation:

   ```
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(BulkDataParams, strUUID, subcam, pts_beg, pts_len, pts_gap, labels)
   ```

   After which you can respell the types in modern fashion without risking any compatibility issues. Note this is also a reason to prefer `qi::auto_` in the start rule there, so you don't get painful surprises when e.g. the parser results get implicitly converted to the target type in expected ways.

   ```
   struct BulkDataParams {
       std::string strUUID;
       int16_t subcam;
       int64_t pts_beg;
       int64_t pts_len;
       int64_t pts_gap;
       label_t labels;
   };
   ```
5. Now let's throw in debug output and a test body:

   **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CSBLSYqbAcepGrou)</kbd>**

   ```
   #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
   #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
   #include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iomanip>

   using label_t = std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int>>;

   namespace std {
       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, label_t::value_type const& t) {
           auto const& [k,v] = t;
           return os << "[" << std::quoted(k) << "," << v << "]";
       }

       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, label_t const& m) {
           os << "{";
           for (auto&& el:m) os << el << ",";
           return os << "}";
       }
   }

   struct BulkDataParams {
       std::string strUUID;
       int16_t subcam;
       int64_t pts_beg;
       int64_t pts_len;
       int64_t pts_gap;
       label_t labels;
   };

   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(BulkDataParams, strUUID, subcam, pts_beg, pts_len, pts_gap, labels)

   template <typename Iterator> struct load_parser : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, BulkDataParams()> {
       load_parser() : load_parser::base_type(start) {
           namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
           namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

           uuid = '"' >> qi::raw [
               hex_<4>{} >> qi::repeat(3)['-' >> hex_<2>{}] >> '-' >> hex_<6>{}
           ] >> '"';

           quoted_string = '"' >> *~qi::char_('"') >> '"';

           label = '{' >> quoted_string >> ',' >> qi::int_ >> '}';

           start = qi::skip(ascii::space) [ '{'
               >> uuid      >> ','
               >> qi::auto_ >> ','
               >> qi::auto_ >> ','
               >> qi::auto_ >> ','
               >> qi::auto_ >> ','
               >> '{' >> -(label % ',') >> '}'
               >> '}' >> ';'
           ];

           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
               (uuid) (quoted_string) (label) (start)
           )
       }

       template<int N> using hex_ = boost::spirit::qi::int_parser<std::intmax_t, 16, 2*N, 2*N>;

     private:
       boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> uuid;
       boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> quoted_string;
       boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, label_t::value_type(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> label;
       boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, BulkDataParams()> start;
   };

   int main() {

       for (std::string const input : {
           R"({ "68965363-2d87-46d4-b05d-f293f2c8403b", 0, 1583798400000000, 86400000000, 600000000, { { "motorbike", 5 }, { "aeroplane", 6 } } };)",
       })
       {
           auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
           BulkDataParams bdp;
           load_parser<std::string::const_iterator> p;
           if (parse(f, l, p, bdp)) {
               std::cout << "Parsed: " << boost::fusion::as_vector(bdp) << "\n";
           } else {
               std::cout << "Parse Failed\n";
           }

           if (f != l) {
               std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Regular output:

   > `Parsed: (68965363-2d87-46d4-b05d-f293f2c8403b 0 1583798400000000 86400000000 600000000 {["motorbike",5],["aeroplane",6],})`

   Debug output:

   ```
   <start>
     <try>{ "68965363-2d87-46d</try>
     <uuid>
       <try>"68965363-2d87-46d4-</try>
       <success>, 0, 158379840000000</success>
       <attributes>[[6, 8, 9, 6, 5, 3, 6, 3, -, 2, d, 8, 7, -, 4, 6, d, 4, -, b, 0, 5, d, -, f, 2, 9, 3, f, 2, c, 8, 4, 0, 3, b]]</attributes>
     </uuid>
     <label>
       <try> { "motorbike", 5 },</try>
       <quoted_string>
         <try>"motorbike", 5 }, { </try>
         <success>, 5 }, { "aeroplane"</success>
         <attributes>[[m, o, t, o, r, b, i, k, e]]</attributes>
       </quoted_string>
       <success>, { "aeroplane", 6 }</success>
       <attributes>[[[m, o, t, o, r, b, i, k, e], 5]]</attributes>
     </label>
     <label>
       <try> { "aeroplane", 6 } </try>
       <quoted_string>
         <try>"aeroplane", 6 } } }</try>
         <success>, 6 } } };</success>
         <attributes>[[a, e, r, o, p, l, a, n, e]]</attributes>
       </quoted_string>
       <success> } };</success>
       <attributes>[[[a, e, r, o, p, l, a, n, e], 6]]</attributes>
     </label>
     <success></success>
     <attributes>[[[6, 8, 9, 6, 5, 3, 6, 3, -, 2, d, 8, 7, -, 4, 6, d, 4, -, b, 0, 5, d, -, f, 2, 9, 3, f, 2, c, 8, 4, 0, 3, b], 0, 1583798400000000, 86400000000, 600000000, [[[m, o, t, o, r, b, i, k, e], 5], [[a, e, r, o, p, l, a, n, e], 6]]]]</attributes>
   </start>
   ```

Comment: How do you generate the debug output?

Comment: It's the `#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` in the full listing. In this case I sneaked a few `operator<<` overloads into `std` namespace to make it pan out for the `label_t`. Note with X3 you would have `BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question. I had made two errors. First, rule `label` had the wrong type of attribute, `std::string()` instead of `std::tuple<std::string, int>()`.

The second error was that I needed to `#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>`. I discovered that only by chance, as this was not in the Spirit 2.5 documentation.

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct load_parser : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, BulkDataParmas(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type>
{
    load_parser() : load_parser::base_type(start)
    {
        namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
        namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
        using qi::attr;
        using qi::short_;
        using qi::int_;
        using qi::long_long;
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::xdigit;
        using qi::lexeme;
        using ascii::char_;
        using boost::proto::deep_copy;

        auto hex2_ = deep_copy(xdigit >> xdigit >> xdigit >> xdigit);
        auto hex4_ = deep_copy(hex2_ >> hex2_);
        auto hex6_ = deep_copy(hex4_ >> hex2_);
        auto fmt_  = deep_copy('"' >> hex4_ >> char_('-') >> hex2_ >> char_('-') >> hex2_ >> char_('-') >> hex2_ >> char_('-') >> hex6_ >> '"');
        uuid = qi::as_string[fmt_];

        quoted_string %= lexeme['"' >> +(char_ - '"') >> '"'];

        label = '{' >> quoted_string >> ',' >> int_ >> '}';

        start = '{' >>  uuid >> ',' >> short_ >> ',' >> long_long >> ',' >> long_long >> ',' >> long_long >> ',' >> '{' >> -(label >> *(',' >> label)) >>'}' >> '}';
//        start = '{' >>  uuid >> ',' >> short_ >> ',' >> long_long >> ',' >> long_long >> ',' >> long_long >> '}';
    }

private:

    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> uuid;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> quoted_string;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::tuple<std::string, int>(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> label;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, BulkDataParmas(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> start;
};
```

Test code:

```
void doTestParser2()
{
    for
    (
        auto& input : std::list<std::string>
        {
            "{ \"68965363-2d87-46d4-b05d-f293f2c8403b\", 0, 1583798400000000, 86400000000, 600000000, {  } };",
            "{ \"68965363-2d87-46d4-b05d-f293f2c8403b\", 0, 1583798400000000, 86400000000, 600000000, { { \"motorbike\", 5 } } };",
            "{ \"68965363-2d87-46d4-b05d-f293f2c8403b\", 0, 1583798400000000, 86400000000, 600000000, { { \"motorbike\", 5 }, { \"aeroplane\", 6 } } };"
        }
    )
    {
        using namespace boost::spirit;

        auto f(std::begin(input)), l(std::end(input));
        load_parser<decltype(f)> p;

        try
        {
            BulkDataParmas result { };
            std::string sresult { };
            bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p > ';', qi::ascii::space, result);

            if (!ok)
                std::cerr << "invalid input" << std::endl;
            else
            {
                std::cout << "ok: " << input << std::endl;
                std::cout << "UUID:     " << result.strUUID << std::endl;
                std::cout << "subcam:   " << result.subcam << std::endl;
                std::cout << "pts_beg:  " << result.pts_beg << std::endl;
                std::cout << "pts_len:  " << result.pts_len << std::endl;
                std::cout << "pts_gap:  " << result.pts_gap << std::endl;
                for (auto const& tup : result.labels)
                {
                    std::cout << "label:    " << std::get<0>(tup) << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "level:    " << std::get<1>(tup) << std::endl;
                }

            }

        }
        catch (const qi::expectation_failure<decltype(f)>& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "expectation_failure at '" << std::string(e.first, e.last) << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```